# Can I write or highlight verses from scriptures?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I just started to read the Gita and I was wondering if I could write or highlight important verses,slokhas and more in it. Can anyone help me please ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can write...

Comment: yes you can write or highlight....

Comment: You will get the complete fruits of Bhagavad gita(or any scripture) only when you understand and follow it. You can highlight without any doubt in your mind. This can be applied to other scriptures too.  All the best.

Comment: yes you can highlight and write your own language to get it better, but you don't cut any line in it. Its directly came from lord krishna. All the Best. Hare Krishna

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely. [Dr. Garikipati Narasimha Rao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garikapati_Narasimha_Rao) in his discourse on Bhagavad-gītā in [this](https://youtu.be/DJHHpT4ZL2I?t=631) YouTube video (Telugu) says you can write, highlight, make notes and do everything you need for śravaṇa (reading), manana (reflection) and nididhyāsana (constant meditation or practice) of Bhagavad-gītā verses.

Remember that nididhyāsana is a million times superior to reading, highlighting etc.

> श्रुतेः शतगुणं विद्यान्मननं मननादपि । 
>  
>   निदिंध्यासं लक्षगुणमनन्तं निर्विकल्पकम् ॥ ३६४ ॥
>
> śruteḥ śataguṇaṃ vidyānmananaṃ mananādapi | 
>  
>   nidiṃdhyāsaṃ lakṣaguṇamanantaṃ nirvikalpakam || 364 ||
>
> 364. Reflection should be considered a hundred times superior to
>   hearing, and meditation a hundred thousand times superior even to
>   reflection, but the Nirvikalpa Samadhi is infinite in its results.
>
> [*Vivekacūḍāmaṇi*](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vivekachudamani/d/doc144799.html)

Comment: Dear sir can you please please share your mail? Or else Can I share? I really want to speak to you please sir !Please dont say no!

Answer (score 4):

The only Restriction on Bhagwad Gita is

> इदं ते नातपस्काय नाभक्ताय कदाचन।
>
> न चाशुश्रूषवे वाच्यं न च मां योऽभ्यसूयति।।18.67।।
>
> This confidential knowledge may never be explained to those who are not austere, or devoted, or engaged in devotional service, nor to one who is envious of Me. [18.67](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-67/)

Commentary by Bhagwad Ramanujacharya

> I have taught you this most secret doctrine. This should not be imparted by you to someone who has not practised austere disciplines. Never should this be taught to someone who is not devoted to Me and to you, the teacher (i.e., when you have to play the role of a teacher of this doctrine). The meaning is that it should not be taught by you to someone who, though practising austerities, is not a devotee and does not serve Me. It is also never to be taught to one who has no wish to listen, even though he is a devotee. Nor should it be imparted to one who traduces Me, that is, who — when My nature, glories and attributes are described — discovers defects in them. The differences of case (from ablative to nominative form) is to teach that the last one is the most despicable character.

---

**Definition(s) of a Bhakta :**

Definition 1

> श्री भगवानुवाच
>
> मय्यावेश्य मनो ये मां नित्ययुक्ता उपासते।
>
> श्रद्धया परयोपेतास्ते मे युक्ततमा मताः।।12.2।।
>
> The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: Those who fix their minds on My personal form and are always engaged in worshiping Me with great and transcendental faith are considered by Me to be most perfect. [12.2](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-12-2)

Commentary by Bhagawad Ramanujacharya

> The Lord said — I consider them to be the highest among the Yogins (i.e., among those striving for realisation) — them who worship Me focusing their minds upon Me as one exceedingly dear to them, who are endowed with supreme faith, and who are ever ‘integrated’ with Me, namely ever desirous of constant union with Me. Those who thus worship Me, focusing their minds on Me as their supreme goal, attain Me soon and easily. Such is the meaning.

Definition 2

> अनपेक्षः शुचिर्दक्ष उदासीनो गतव्यथः।
>
> सर्वारम्भपरित्यागी यो मद्भक्तः स मे प्रियः।।12.16।।
>
> My devotee who is not dependent on the ordinary course of activities, who is pure, expert, without cares, free from all pains, and not striving for some result, is very dear to Me. [12.16](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-12-16/)

Commentary by Bhagawad Ramanujacharya

> He who is free from ‘desires’, i.e., who has no longing for anything except the self; who is ‘pure’, namely, whose body is nourished on the food prescribed by the Sastras; who is an ‘expert’ namely, who is an expert in performing actions prescribed by the Sastras; who is ‘indifferent’, i.e., not interested in matters other than those enjoined by the Sastras; who is free from ‘agony’, i.e., of pain caused by heat, cold, contact with coarse things etc., which are inevitably associated with the performance of rites prescribed by the Sastras; who renounces all ‘undertakings,’ i.e., who renounces all undertakings except those demanded by the Sastras — the devotee who is like this is dear to Me.

---

**Bhakta Lakshana (Identification of Bhaktas) :**

> अद्वेष्टा सर्वभूतानां मैत्रः करुण एव च।
>
> निर्ममो निरहङ्कारः समदुःखसुखः क्षमी।।12.13।।
>
> सन्तुष्टः सततं योगी यतात्मा दृढनिश्चयः।
>
> मय्यर्पितमनोबुद्धिर्यो मद्भक्तः स मे प्रियः।।12.14।।
>
> One who is not envious but is a kind friend to all living entities, who does not think himself a proprietor and is free from false ego, who is equal in both happiness and distress, who is tolerant, always satisfied, self-controlled, and engaged in devotional service with determination, his mind and intelligence fixed on Me—such a devotee of Mine is very dear to Me.
>   [12.13-12.14](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-12-13-14/)

Commentary By Bhagwad Ramanujacharya

> In these and succeeding verses the Lord mentions the nature of the Karma Yogi who adores Him through his works. **In other words the Bhakti element in Karma Yoga is emphasised**. He never hates any being even though they hate him and do him wrong. For he thinks that the Lord impels these beings to hate him and do him wrong for atoning for his transgressions. He is ‘friendly’, evincing a friendly disposition towards all beings whether they hate him or do him wrong. He is ‘compassionate’, evincing compassion towards their sufferings. He is free from the ‘feeling of mine,’ i.e., he is not possessive with regard to his body, senses and all things associated with them. He is free from the feeling of ‘I’, i.e., is free from the delusion that his body is the self. Therefore, ‘pain and pleasure are the same to him,’ i.e., he is free from distress and delight resulting from pain and pleasure arising from his deeds. He is ‘enduring’, unaffected even by those two (i.e., pleasure and pain) due to the inevitable contact of sense-objects. He is ‘content’, namely, satisfied with whatever chance may bring him for the sustenance of his body. He ‘ever meditates,’ i.e., is constantly intent on contemplating on the self as separate from the body. He is ‘self-restrained’, namely, he controls the activities of his mind. He is of ‘firm conviction’ regarding the meanings taught in the science of the self. His ‘mind and reason are dedicated to Me’ i.e., his mind and reason are dedicated to Me in the form ‘Bhagavan Vasudeva alone is propitiated by disinterested activities, and when duly propitiated, He wil bring about for me the direct vision of the self.’ Such a devotee of mine, i.e., who works in this manner as a Karma Yogin, is dear to Me.

On a side note you should never give Bhagwad gita or any Bhagwata shastras to the people who are envious to Shriman Narayana, giving gold to cobbler is of no use. So while distributing this Ambrosia be cautious.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58705/discussion-on-answer-by-yogi-can-i-write-or-highlight-verses-from-scriptures).