# Is it necessary to read the Mahatmya in Bhagavad-Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I read the Bhagavad-Gita every day. There are stories at the beginning of each chapter named "Mahatmya" from the book I have. I skip the story before any chapter of Bhagavad-Gita.

My question is that is it necessary to read those stories related to Mahatmya before reading the Bhagavad-Gita's any chapter?
[image: Please check below image of my Geetaji]

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha if you find rude comments flag it as unfriendly and when situation demands you can use custom flag for moderators intervention citing reasons

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha If u can provide screenshots from the book it will be clear to us what u are talking about

Comment: @Wikash_hindu avoid posting unwelcoming or criticizing in comments. Take a look at [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: @Rickross Please have a look at my Gitaji's image.

Comment: The Gita-Mahatmya of the Padma-Purana does NOT contain any stories. Itgives the Mahatmya of each chapter in a sloka and is normally read in entirety aftervchanting of the entire Gita.

Comment: Is it necessary to read the Mahatmya? Or just read the chapter

Comment: Yes now its clear to me and I hv answered @RavindraKushwaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your book is excellent because it not only gives the Bhagavad Gita slokas but along with also provides the Gita Mahatyam (the greatness of Gita) as found in the Padma Purana.

**It is clearly written over the cover of your book that it includes the greatness of Gita's each chapters as found in the Padma Purana (read the lines "Padma Purana antargata pratyek adhyayke etc").**

In the Padma Purana, there are separate chapters dedicated to describing the greatness of Bhagavad Gita.

For example, the greatness of the first chapter is described thus with the help of an incident.

> Fully endorsing what Devi Lakshmi said, Bhagavan defined that out of
>   the Eighteen ‘Adhyayas’ (Chapters) of Bhagavad Gita, five Adhyayas
>   constituted five of his Faces, ten Adhyayas were his ten hands, one
>   Adhyaya was his belly and two were his two feet. He further gave the
>   illustration of Susharma and said that intelligent people like him who
>   read an Adhyaya of Gita a day or half of it or a quarter, or atleast a
>   stanza, would certainly secure Mukti. Susharma was no doubt a Brahmana
>   by birth but was a chronic sinner; he did neither dhyana nor japa,
>   neither homa nor ‘Atithi Satkar’ or Puja of Guests; on the contrary he
>   was a drunkard, meat eater and a regular womanizer. One day he died of
>   a snake bite. After experiencing retribution in various ‘Narakas’, he
>   was born as a bull and served under an oil-extractor for seven to
>   eight years and died out of hard work and exhaustion. A few persons
>   contributed prayers for the animal’s salvation and among them was a
>   ‘veshya’ (prostitute) who donated some ‘Punya’ on her account. In the
>   rebirth the bull became a pious Brahmana in the same village as a
>   ‘Jyatismara’ with the gift of memory of the past birth. He met the
>   Veshya and enquired as to which Punya that she donated at the death of
>   the bull. She said that she bought a parrot which used to mutter some
>   lines of a stanza always although she did not guess what was it but
>   surely that muttering had highly soothing effect. The Brahmana asked
>   the Parrot and the latter said that she was earlier in an Ashram in a
>   cage where a Rishi was teaching something to his desciples and it
>   learnt it but a hunter stole the bird and sold to the Veshya. The
>   Rishi conveyed that he taught the First Chapter of Gita! That was the
>   Punya which the Veshya acquired from the parrot’s muttering that was
>   learnt at the Ashram. Such was the Mahtmya of the First Chapter.

Source - [Essence of Padma Purana.](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/padmapurana30.html)

In a similar way, the greatness of all the other chapters also discussed in the same Purana. And, each is accompanied with an incident.

So, these are the stories your book is having along with each chapters (Adhyaya).

It is not mandatory to read these stories while you are reciting the Gita slokas. But if you want to read that's your choice.

The Gita Parayana rules that are given in one of my books does not make it mandatory to read Gita Mahatyam. Simply reciting the slokas of the text is good enough.

Comment: No need of calling me sir .. and you are welcome ... :) @RavindraKushwaha

Comment: I hv no problems in calling it an incident , I just used the word the author used in the Q @Pratimaputra

Answer (score 5):

There are actually no stories in the beginning of chapters in the Bhagavad Gita. Bhagavad Gita is a conversation between Krishna and Arjuna. The passages are  commentator and translator's addition before the chapter begins. These are added so as to understand the chapter better. The eighteen chapters of Bhagavad Gita are named because of the topic discussed in that particular chapter.

Chapter 1: Vishada Yoga

Chapter 2: Sankhya Yoga

Chapter 3: Karma Yoga

Chapter 4: Jnana Yoga

Chapter 5 : Karma Vairagya Yoga

Chapter 6: Abhyasa Yoga

Chapter 7: Paramahamsa Vijnana Yoga

Chapter 10: Vibhuti-Vistara-Yoga

Chapter 11: Visvarupa-Darsana Yoga

Chapter 12: Bhakti Yoga

Chapter 13: Ksetra-Ksetrajna Vibhaga Yoga

Chapter 14: Gunatraya-Vibhaga Yoga

Chapter 15: Purushottama Yoga

Chapter 16: Daiva Asura Sampat Vibhaga Yoga

Chapter 17: Shraddhatraya Vibhaga Yoga

Chapter 18: Moksa-Opadesa Yoga

If you are reading Bhagavad Gita as parayana for fulfillment of some wish, it is not necessary to read the introduction given by the translator. These are not part of Bhagavad Gita. But for reading for understanding the message and implementing it in our life, it is recommended. The message given by Krishna to Arjuna is for implementing. For implementation, you need to understand it in detail. Reading without implementation is not fruitful.

In Vivekachudamani, Adi Shankaracharya says:

> śruteḥ śataguṇaṃ vidyānmananaṃ mananādapi |
>   nidiṃdhyāsaṃ lakṣaguṇamanantaṃ nirvikalpakam || 364 ||
>
> Reflection should be considered a hundred times superior to hearing, and meditation a hundred thousand times superior even to reflection, but the Nirvikalpa Samadhi is infinite in its results.

Related - [Can I write or highlight verses from scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17312/5212)

Comment: I daily read Geetaji...Before each chapter there is story called ~mahatv~ in it there story of people who read the Geeta ji and getting the blessing of God.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Okay. These stories from Gita Mahatmaya are not a part of Bhagavad Gita. So, you may skip them. But try to  understand the meaning of Gita verses completely I guess these are part of Padma Purana Uttara Khanda.

Comment: Thanks @Sarvabhour .. Means I can skip this `Mahatmaya` before reading any chapter on Geetaji.

Comment: @Pratimaputra I have the Gitaji in which **Mahatmaya** is there before chapters.  Please be sure before saying meaningless to this Question

Comment: But bro, i have Gitaji, where before each chapter there is **Mahatmaya** , therefore i have asked the question here

Comment: @Pratimaputra No one asked if questions and answers are meaningless. This is written in Pure English and not in some unknown script. If there are any mistakes feel free to correct them. Care to read what is question and answer properly? That is how many writes answers here. There are comments to ask clarifications. Use those comments and try to understand the question and answer.

Comment: @Pratimaputra I am taking about Bhagavad Gita here. There are many thousands of publications which have purports, translation comments and statements so that the reader understands the chapter properly. Not only that, it applies to many books. When you buy books especially for Parayana, they have parayana vidhi and related stories also. It varies with books and traditions.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma One should be very careful in choosing the book then and so Guru and lineage are essential to read and understand the meanings of the scriptures.One should choose th eAcharya first.Otherwise he should read translations without purport of some dependable publications like Gita press.Anyone can write any purport or any mahatmya but God us given us intelligence to judge:)

Comment: @Pratimaputra That is the not the question here. Are you aware of the Gita Mahahtmya from Padma Purana? There are 1000's of books. If there is no good translation, why would anyone chose it?!. The question here is whether or not to read mahatmya stories as a part of Bhagavad Gita or not.

Comment: Please have a look on my edited question.. I have posted the image of Gitaji