# Is there praise of Krishna's Bhagavad Gita in scripture?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Scriptures often praise themselves or other scriptures.  Is there praise of Krishna's Bhagavad Gita in canonical Sanskrit scripture?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [Bhagavad Gita Mahatamya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavad-gita-mahatmya/d/doc365756.html) is found in Padma Purana’s Uttar-Khanda. It contains dedicated chapter in praise of each chapter of BG.

Related: [Is it necessary to read the Mahatmya in Bhagavad-Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34300/is-it-necessary-to-read-the-mahatmya-in-bhagavad-gita)